# how can i stack videos which have different durations?

Tags: ffmpeg

I made a ffmpeg filter graph using hstack to merge two videos. The two videos have different durations. One has 1:30 and the other has 8:48 length.

I had expected the output video has 8:48, but the result was 2:14. Is this hstack filter spec?

And is there any other solution?

command line is here. (these webms have only video streams)

`ffmpeg -i vonly_short.webm -i vonly_long.webm -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:270, pad=480:270:-1:-1[v0];[1:v]scale=-1:270, pad=480:270:-1:-1[v1]; [v0][v1]hstack=2:0[outv]" -map [outv] -c:v vp8 out.webm`

Comment: Show the complete log from the command.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.
overlay helps it.

Comment: Imagine having the same question and then finding this as the answer. A more detailed answer would be appreciated by others who may have the same question.